# Why do I only have to escape the last backslash in a string literal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping, python-3.7, string-literals

I have the following Python code:

```
localExtractpath = "D:\Python\From 0 to 1\Excel\"
if os.path.exists(localZipPath):
    print("Cool! '" + localZipPath + "' exists...proceeding...")
```

This gives me the error:

```
File "", line 2
    localExtractpath = "D:\Python\From 0 to 1\Excel\"
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

When I escape the last `\` in the string, the code works. Why do I only have to escape the last `\`?

Comment: Because that `\\` is escaping the double-quote after it - so your string is malformed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last backslash in `"D:\Python\From 0 to 1\Excel\"` is escaping your ending quotation mark, so in the eyes of the interpreter, your string is unterminated. In fact, you have to escape all your backslashes if you want to use the literal backslash in your string:

`"D:\\Python\\From 0 to 1\\Excel\\"`

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I only have to escape the last \?

Because only after the last `\` there is a symbol (`"`) which together with `\` forms an *escape sequence* — `\"` (escaping the role of the quote symbol `"` as a string terminator).

If  `\` with subsequent symbol(s) *don't form an escape sequence*, it's kept *as is,* i.e. as the backslash symbol itself.

(In your case neither `\P`, nor `\F` and nor `\E` form an allowed escape sequence, so the symbol `\` itself is interpreted literally — as is.)

---

*An (unsolicited) solution:*

Use *forward slashes* (`/`) instead of backslashes (`\`) 
(all Windows system calls accept them, too):

```
localExtractpath = "D:/Python/From 0 to 1/Excel/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are right: you should escape all your backslashes and, even better, you should use forward slash for path elements (you can even take a look at the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib#module-pathlib) library).

But to answer specifically your question on why the issue lies only in the last one and not in the previous backslashes, you should take a look at the definition of [string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

You will see that there is a (short) list of characters for which the backslash makes something particular. For the rest, the backslash is taken as itself.

For instance `"\n"` is interpreted not as a string with two characters (`\` and `n`) but as a string with only a single line-feed character.
That is not the case with `"\P"`, `"\F"` or `"\E"` which are two characters each since they don't have a specific meaning.

`\"` and `\'` are particular in that they allow to respectively insert a `"` or `'` character in a string literal delimited by this same character.
For example, `'single: \', double "'` and `"single: ', double: \""` are two ways to define the `single: ', double "` string literal.